# Can you change the base date for .net automatic versioning?

Tags: visual-studio, versioning, build-numbers

I've set the AssemblyVersion property of a project to 3.0.* to get automatic build numbers generated whenever I do a new build of my project. The build number generated is the number of days elapsed since January 1, 2000. This means that if I do a build today, it will be build 3703. I would like to start with lower build numbers. Is there a way for me to reset the base date to a date of my choice?

Comment: Yes, type in the number yourself.  You shouldn't be auto-incrementing [AssemblyVersion] anyway, only [AssemblyFileVersion].  Which isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a macro and/or VS plugin to do this for you. You can find some information for older versions of Visual Studio at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/VSBuildNumberAutomation.aspx) or [Codeguru.](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_vs_addins/visualstudioadd-ins/article.php/c5965)